# Importing "sub" modules to be own "sub" modules

Tags: python, import, module

Assume you have a package `foo` with the following `__init__.py`:

```
from bar import *
```

With `bar` being any python module installed with `pip install bar`.

Now what always works when you can import `bar`:

```
from bar import submodule #works
import bar.submodule      #works, too
```

Now I would assume the following things would **all** work as well:

```
from foo import submodule     # a) is possible
import foo.submodule          # b) not possible ("no module named submodule")
from foo.bar import submodule # c) also impossible ("no module named submodule")
```

Why are they not possible? What would I need to do to make them possible, from the point of view of the `foo` maintainer?

Comment: relative imports only work within packages ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`submodule` and `bar` are members of the `foo` module object, not submodules of it.  Therefore, they behave just like any other member attribute of `foo`.  You can bring them into the module namespace of a third module with the `from foo import ...` form, but you can't directly `import` them relative to `foo`.  I guess you could if you hacked them in to `sys.modules` under the desired name manually, but you really shouldn't be doing anything like that...

To illustrate the issue:

`foo.py`

```
# x and y are values in the foo namespace, available as member attributes
# of the foo module object when foo is imported elsewhere
x = 'x'
y = 'y'
```

`bar.py`

```
# the foo module object is added as a member attribute of bar on import
# with the name foo in the bar namespace
import foo
# the same foo object is aliased within the bar namespace with the name
# fooy
import foo as fooy
# foo.x and foo.y are referenced from the bar namespace as x and y,
# available as member attributes of the bar module object
from foo import x, y
# z is a member attribute of the bar module object
z = 'z'
```

`baz.py`

```
# brings a reference to the x, y, and z attributes of bar (x and y
# come in turn from foo, though that's not relevant to the import;
# it just cares that bar has x, y, and z attributes), in to the
# namespace of baz
from bar import x, y, z
# won't work, because foo is a member of bar, not a submodule
import bar.foo
# will work, for the same reason that importing x, y, and z work
from bar import foo
```